# Git Rebase Include Specific Commits

Tags: git

```
Foo:
A-O-X-Y-Z
Bar:
A-B-C-D
```

I am looking to understand what is the correct strategy to achieve this. When I do a rebase of branch Foo against Bar, I get the following branch output.

```
I ran:
git checkout Foo
git rebase Bar
# fix merge errors and push

Resulting Foo branch:
A-B-C-D-O-X-Y-Z
```

What I am trying to ask is, is it possible to rebase and include only a specific set of commits (X,Y,Z)? I want to achieve this so the `"O"` commit is excluded.

```
Desired Result:
A-B-C-D-X-Y-Z
```

Comment: You could use `rebase onto` or `cherry-pick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to achieve the result you desire.
The command you need is:

```
git rebase --onto Bar Foo~3 Foo
```

This form of `rebase` that takes two references as arguments (ignore `--onto Bar` for now) is a shortcut for the following two commands:

```
git checkout Foo
git rebase --onto Bar Foo~3
```

### How it works

Without `--onto Bar`, the `rebase` command above gets the commits from the current branch (`Foo`) that are not accessible from `Foo~3` and saves them in a temporary area. Then it resets the current branch to `Foo~3` and applies the saved commits one by one, in their original order.

With `--onto Bar`, the saving and restoring of the commits happens the same way but the restoring starts on top of the commit identified by `Bar` instead of `Foo~3`.

All in all, the command above takes the most recent 3 commits from the branch `Foo` (together with the `Foo` branch) and puts them on top of the commit identifies by `Bar`.

### Warning!

If, after you run this command, the commit `O` cannot be accessed starting from a branch, it will disappear from the history. It is not removed immediately. You can still access it for a while if you know its hash or by inspecting the output of `git reflog`. Git will remove it completely after a while (usually about two weeks) if it is not accessible any more using a branch, tag or the reflog.

In fact, nothing is removed immediately; even the commits that `git rebase` "moved" from one branch to another were actually copied and the originals are still in the repository and they are accessible but not visible.

Read more about [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) on the Git website or run `git help rebase` on your terminal.